# How does $-(-1)^n$ become $(-1)^{n+1}$

Tags: proof-writing, arithmetic

I am currently studying how to prove the Fibonacci Identity by Simple Induction, shown [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20180128160657/http://mathforum.org/library/drmath/view/52718.html), however I do not understand how $-(-1)^n$ becomes $(-1)^{n+1}$.  Can anybody explain to me the logic behind this?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

$-(-1)^n=(-1)^1(-1)^n=(-1)^{n+1}$

Answer (score 6):

$$-x=(-1)x$$
Now substitute $x=(-1)^n$
$$-(-1)^n=(-1)(-1)^n=(-1)^{n+1}$$

Answer (score 4):

The negative sign *outside* the parentheses can be re-written as $-1$:
$$-(-1)^n = (-1)(-1)^n$$
That first factor of $(-1)$ can be written as $(-1)^1$, so we have
$$(-1)^1(-1)^n$$
and finally the two factors can be combined by adding the exponents:
$$(-1)^{n+1}$$

Answer (score 2):

The powers of $-1$ are $$-1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1, \ldots$$ If $n$ is odd, then $(-1)^n = -1$, but if $n$ is even then $(-1)^n = 1$. So if you multiply $(-1)^n$ once by $-1$, it is the same as incrementing $n$. (Technically you can also decrement, but you can't generalize that to other negative numbers).

Answer (score 0):

Simple there is a $-$ sign in front so you can write $-(-1)^n=(-1)(-1)^n=(-1)^{n+1}$.